# Using jquery ajax upload file then get json format reponse but can not be display json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement upload file with jQuery and php. The process I want to implement is :

1. Select file;
2. Click upload button;
3. Get response from php server;
4. Display response;

However, I just can't make response display as it should be, instead, it is always undefined.

The htm.twig (I'm using twig) looks like this:

```html
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var form_data = new FormData();
            var file_data = $("#upload_input")[0].files;
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php?act=upload",
                data : form_data,
                type : 'POST',
                processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                success : function (data) {
                    alert(data.code);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    ...
    <input type="file" id="upload_input" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="upload"/>
```

Php script is:

```php
<?php
    include_once "lib/TwigService.php";

    $act = $_REQUEST['act'] ?? '';
    if ($act == 'upload') {
        $msg = array(
            'code' => 0,
            'msg' => 'nothing',
            'data' => 'none'
        );
        echo json_encode($msg);
        die();
    }


    $twig = new TwigService("../resource/templates");
    $twig->render("upload.htm.twig");
```

Please tell me where is wrong with my code.Thanks!

---

It is my mistake that not clearly tell you guys what response I want display through `alert`.

As you may see in code, the reponse I want from server is json data, with three field : code, msg, data.

When the front get the response, it should display this three field by `data.<name>`. The result is the response I got in front is correct, but it displayed as `undefined`.

Though a right awnser has been accept (Thanks for your help), for the understanding of who has same trouble as me, I make this illustration.

Comment: WHat response does not display or does not display how you expect? Are you expecting to run the twig, or the `echo json_encode()` and `die()`

Comment: Have you checked your browser's network inspector to see if the request is sent as expected, and to see what the response is?

Comment: You can also dump the response to see what it looks like in the console by using `console.log(data)` instead of `alert(data.code)`. It could be that you get a string back and not an object. Try adding `dataType: 'json',` as a setting for your ajax request.

Comment: @Riton Elion Please check answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Use dataType as JSON

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php?act=upload",
            data : form_data,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : "json",
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success : function (data) {
                alert(data.code);
            },
        });
```

Step2: Use JSON.parse() method

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php?act=upload",
            data : form_data,
            type : 'POST',
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success : function (data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(result);
            },
        });
```